# Alter input value with template binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input component for time. I want to perform some input modifications to keep time inside limits.

This is an excerpt from HTML markup

```
<input
        (change)="hoursChange($event.target.value)"
        (keypress)="onlyNumHandler($event)"
        (blur)="onBlur('hours')"
        [ngModel]="hours"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        [disabled]="!dateVal"
        placeholder="23"
        type="text"
        matInput
    >
```

Here dateVal is a Moment instance.

And this is my function to alter hours on input

```
hoursChange(val: string): void {
        const numVal = Number(val);

        if (isNaN(numVal) || !isFinite(numVal)) {
            this.hours = '00';
        } else if (numVal > 23) {
            this.hours = '23';
        } else {
            this.hours = val;
        }

        this.dateVal.set({
            hour: Number(this.hours)
        });

        this.changeDate(this.dateVal);
    }
```

The problem here is that I cannot make it work on input. It alters input value only on blur.
If I change `(change)` on `(input)` it alters the value only once when it hits max limit.

The trick is that function sets everything successfully (i.e. `hours` prop is at it should be and moment object has the proper hours set), however the input value shown is still not `23` but `999` (in case of `999` input).

I don't know if it matters, but I've enabled `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

---

An approximate behaviour I'm observing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjlded

Comment: Can you please make a snippet using stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 0):

So I would suggest another approach is to pass the element ref to the function then update it's value: [Stackbliz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rifqj3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Pass the element ref in template:

```
<input  
        #input
        //Pass the element ref into hoursChange(...)
        (ngModelChange)="hoursChange($event, input)"
        (keypress)="onlyNumHandler($event)"
        (blur)="onBlur('hours')"
        [ngModel]="hours"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        [disabled]="!dateVal"
        placeholder="23"
        type="text"
        matInput
    >
```

In your TS

```
  hoursChange(val: string, input ): void {
    const numVal = Number(val);

    if (isNaN(numVal) || !isFinite(numVal)) {
      this.hours = '00';
    } else if (numVal > 23) {
      this.hours = '23';
    } else {
      this.hours = val;
    }
    //Change via element ref
    input.value = this.hours;   

    this.dateVal.set({
      hour: Number(this.hours)
    });
  }
```

**Explain for the problem:**

If you look at the [**source code of the ngModel directive**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts),in **`line 221`** the **`ngOnChange`** trigger function **`isPropertyUpdated()`** - which is the condition for **`ngModelChange`** event to emit the changed value and update **`viewModel`**, that function declared inside [**shared.ts**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts) file in **`line 153`**.

And I believe that function **`isPropertyUpdated()`** going to return false except for the first time change event fired - which cause the binded variable from your component.ts through **`[ngModel]`** to template actually work onetime only (the first time change event fired).

And I think it happen when the banana in the box **`[(ngModel)]`** is splitted which make the model become **`looseIdentical`** and still i have not found the answer that satisfied me yet about angular **`looseIdentical`** definition. But I hope the above informations could help you with this.

Comment: I've tried this first. This doesn't make input shown value change

Comment: Same result as if I used `(change)`